# Need assistance delaying javascript while waiting for Sharepoint list item deletion.

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to automate updating of 8 region lists in SharePoint 2010. The process incudes 1) publishing a master list of all 8 regions from a spreadhseet, 2) deleting all list items in 8 region lists, 3) copying region specific items from the master list into the specific region lists. Each component of the process works flawlessly when executed individually. Now, I'm just trying to put the steps into loop to process all three steps for all 8 regions automatically.

One of the main problems is, once I submit a request to delete the list items from Region 1, I am unable to copy the new contents until the delete it finished. Of course my sript says it's done, but all it has done was submit the request to SharePoint. SharePoint may take anwhere from 15 seconds to 1 minute to actually delete the list items.

So, once I submit the delete, I enter another loop that queries the Region 1 list size. Once it confirms the list is down to zero items, I would like to continue with the copy. Now, the "query the size" loop bombs with different errors such as "the list does not exist", etc. Here's the extracted, pertinent pieces of my code. If anyone has suggestions for fix/improvement, I would greatly welcome the feedback.

```
//Loop through X (8) regions and delete all list items from 'Inventory Region X' List

function main() {
    for (var i=1;i<9;i++)
    {
        alert("Enter Delete Loop " + i);
        listname = "Inventory Region " + i;

        // Submit the delete request
        deletetheregionitems(i);

        // Wait for the delete to complete
        controllistcount = null;
        alert("Begin delay cycle.");
        while (controllistcount != 0)
        {
            countoflistitems(listname);
        }
        controllistcount = null;
        alert("Exit loop!");
    }

    alert("All Region Lists should now be empty.");
}

function countoflistitems(listname) {
    // Get the count of items in the requested list
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listname); 
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>');
    this.listItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery); 
    clientContext.load(listItems, 'Include(Id)'); 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.countretrieveSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.queryFailed));
}


function countretrieveSucceeded(sender, args) {
    controllistcount = listItems.get_count();
}
```

Comment: you may consider using workers

Comment: im not experinced with share point at all , if you can explain the problem from the js aspect , i may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks ProllyGeek. Basically one of the functions is making an external call to a web server asking it to perform a task. The server will not respond to me when it's done, so I need to loop through an additional request to see for myself if it's done. Once I know it's complete, I want to continue with my script.

Comment: ok good to know , so is the problem that you have to check yourself ( need an automated response) ? or that you cant check yourself

Comment: The server is basically deleting items from a table and I need to wait until they are all deleted before copying new records into it. So I am sending a request to the server to ask how many items are currently in the table. Once the server returns 0, I can move on. So I query the server in a loop until I get 0 then I exit the loop and continue with the copy. Seems like until I leave the loop, the server doesn't begin the delete. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use Promises to pause until the delete callback resolves before adding new.  Don't repeatedly poll the server.  Pseudo code:

```
deleteItems().then(){
    addNewItems();

}

function deleteItems(){
    var dfd=jQuery.deferred;
    [JSOM code to delete items]
    executeQueryAsync(function(){
        dfd.resolve();
    }, null);
    return dfd.promise();

}
```

I'm typing this from memory on my phone so that isn't exactly right but its close and should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to read up on promises. I'll give this a try this coming week. Thanks for the great idea!

Comment: Sounded like a terrific idea. However my client is using IE and this browser does not support promises. Thanks for the education, however.

Comment: No version of IE supports Promises natively, but jf you use the implementation of Promises in a library like JQuery then they work fine in IE